# Add 3 text boxes in a html page to calculate the following formula ((a*b)+(b*c))/(a+b)

Tags: javascript

I was trying to create a html page. Here I need to add 3 text boxes in which the user will input 3 numbers :a,b,c

Then I need to add a button that once clicked will calculate the following formula:
((a*b)+(b*c))/(a+b).

The result will be displayed in an alert.

This is my code so far:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="exercitiu1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="formrow">
            <span class="labelstyle">Nr1:</span><input type="text" id="Nr1" class="textbox1style" />
        </div>
        <div class="formrow">
            <span class="labelstyle">Nr2: </span><input type="text" id="Nr2" class="textbox2style" />
        </div>
        <div class="formrow">
            <span class="labelstyle">Nr3: </span><input type="text" id="Nr3" class="textbox3style" />
        </div>
            <span>Result: </span> <div id="calc-result">===</div>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Multiply" onclick = "Multiply();" />
        </body>
</html>

function Multiply()
{
    var a = document.getElementById("Nr1");
    var b = document.getElementById("Nr2");
    var c = document.getElementById("Nr3");
    
    var product = document.getElementById("calc-result");
    
    product.innerHTML = parseInt(a.value) * parseInt(b.value);
    product.innerHTML = parseInt(b.value) * parseInt(c.value);
}
```

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Comment: I need help to solve this.

Comment: Start by putting the function `Multiply` in a script tag.

Comment: Then tidy the html code. It's wrongly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to handle in your question, so buckle up.

Use a `<form>` element to wrap around your inputs. This enables you to listen for the `submit` event and use the [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) constructor to get all the values from your inputs inside of that form. It takes away the task of selecting each and every input field and read its value.

If you want the user to input *only* numbers, then switch to `type="number"` input fields. It will prevent any character other than `0-9` to be used inside of it.

[`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) is an element that accompanies `<input>` elements by describing what they are for. Use these instead of `<span>` elements. The `for` attribute on a `<label>` should point to the `id` of the `<input>` that it is paired with.

The submit behavior of the form should be disabled in the event handler with `event.preventDefault()`. Now you can write your own behavior when submitting the form, like doing your calculation with all the values inside of it.

I've changed the `<div id="calc-result">` to an [`<output>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output) element which can be used to display calculations as a result from input elements.

The example below shows all the examples from above in a working snippet. I'd suggest that you try to learn these elements as they are an essential part of your HTML form kit.

```js
const multiplyForm = document.querySelector('#multiply-form');
const product = document.querySelector("#calc-result");

multiplyForm.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  const formData = new FormData(event.target);
  const a = Number(formData.get('a'));
  const b = Number(formData.get('b'));
  const c = Number(formData.get('c'));
  product.value = ((a * b) + (b * c)) / (a + b);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form id="multiply-form">
  <div class="formrow">
    <label for="Nr1" class="labelstyle">Nr1:</label>
    <input type="number" name="a" id="Nr1" class="textbox1style" />
  </div>
  <div class="formrow">
    <label for="Nr2" class="labelstyle">Nr2: </label>
    <input type="number" name="b" id="Nr2" class="textbox2style" />
  </div>
  <div class="formrow">
    <label for="Nr3" class="labelstyle">Nr3: </label>
    <input type="number" name="c" id="Nr3" class="textbox3style" />
  </div>
  <div class="formrow">
    <label for="calc-result">Result: </label>
    <output id="calc-result" for="Nr1 Nr2 Nr3"></output>
  </div>
  <div class="formrow">
    <button type="submit">Multiply</button>
  </div>
</form>
```